# OutOfMemoryError in Image Loader, App getting crash in android

Tags: android, memory, out-of-memory

I am using universal image loader class and after sometimes app gets crash and giving the below error :

```
java.lang.java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (stack size 16384 bytes) failed: Try again in android: pthread_create (stack size 16384 bytes) failed: Try again
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Show us the code where the error occured and a full stack trace please. It will help other people to undestand the reason of the problem

Comment: @SergeyPekar private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
try {
executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
} catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
e.printStackTrace();
System.out.println("Error in image loader class");
}

}
This is my code, where i am using image loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions.
I was doing silly mistake, i was instantiating ImageLoader object in getView.
So because of that outOfMemory occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Your app is either leaking memory, or allocating too many objects, eventually running out of memory to create threads. Could be in UIL usage too.

According to Universal Image Loader documentation, in case its [usage results in Out of Memory error you should try the below](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info), quoting...

- Disable caching in memory. If OOM is still occurs then it seems your app has a memory leak. Use MemoryAnalyzer to detect it. Otherwise try the following steps (all of them or several):
  Reduce thread pool size in configuration (.threadPoolSize(...)). 1 - 5 is recommended.
- Use .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) in display options. Bitmaps in RGB_565 consume 2 times less memory than in ARGB_8888.
- Use .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
- Use .diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 320, null) in configuratio"

Answer (score 1):

its because your file size of that image is too heavy . and every time it runs or it loaded it will create its different space into stack. so try to change size of image if it's possible. or you can use following command if you are using android version up from 3.x

```
android:largeheap="true"
```

write this code in your manifest file under application tag.